# Float to top unknown height divs

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have some divs in my layout having 50% width. Each div may have a variable height depending on its content. What I would like to do is "floating" them to the top. This means that each div fills gaps with above divs. Something like that:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this effect with some CSS? Of course, width can also be set to other values, not only 50%. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add Code that you have tried

Comment: You will need to opt jQuery solution, take a look here http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @RaunakKathuria: here's the CSS class I am using.

[code]
.span2 {
  float:left;
  width:48%;
  margin:1%;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:top;
}
[/code]

Comment: @Mr.Alien: thanks for the answer, my first choice is pure CSS but if there isn't a solution, this javascript does exactly what I want.

Comment: @Giorgio You can use `column-count` property but that will chop your element if it exceeds the height of the container element

Comment: @Mr.Alien: you're right, but it doesn't keep the order I would like to have. With `column-count` div will be ordered vertically. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You have to use js way, html was not designed to be optimized for vertical alignment. You can use js as suggested by @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 2):

You can change the html markup as follows

```
 <div class="left col50">
        <div class="first"></div>
        <div class="third"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="right col50">
        <div class="second"></div>
        <div class="fourth"></div>
     </div>
```

and the css

```
.col50{
 width:50%;
 }

 .right,.left{
 float:left;
 }
```

Comment: I think it's an interesting point of view: divide everything in two columns and float everything inside. Really cool! +1 for you!